# mouse click and drag not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a external window I am sending a mouse click and drag to. For some reason it isn't dragging it. Any help is much appreciated.

```
        public void clickAndDrag(Point pointA, Point pointB)
    {
        Point tmp = Cursor.Position;

        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Cursor.Position = ConvertToScreenPixel(pointA);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Cursor.Position = ConvertToScreenPixel(pointB);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);


        Cursor.Position = tmp;
    }
```

Comment: You mean an external window that does not belong to your program? And you want to change its position?

Comment: External window does not belong to me, I do not have access to its code. I do not want to change the window position as I can do that already using a different method. I want to click on a coordinate, hold the click until I reach a second coordinate and the release the click.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible. What you want to do is send it a message, and if it is not designed to accept your message and give you result back there is no way around it. You need that Window's code to make it accept your method and act accordingly.

Comment: Why is it not possible? I can send click commands to it and it works, I can also send button presses to the window and it works via the window handle. Normal left clicking works currently but I just cant get it to simulate a mouse click hold release.

Comment: @AmmarSalman : Of course it is possible. `mouse_event` puts mouse data in the mouse input stream, thus it behaves just like if you would move the mouse manually. Because of that it is also not targeted at a specific window.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. You need to slowly move the mouse I guess. But this worked to click and drag to the left a bit. It is total garbage but I am too tired to try to refactor it.

```
        public void clickAndDrag(Point pointA)
    {
        Point tmp = Cursor.Position;
        pointA.X = pointA.X + 20;
        pointA.Y = pointA.Y + 20;

        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Cursor.Position = ConvertToScreenPixel(pointA);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            pointA.X = pointA.X - 10;
            Cursor.Position = ConvertToScreenPixel(pointA);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.MOVE), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }


        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);


        Cursor.Position = tmp;
    }
```